# Python Regex: extract "a" from "01a"

Tags: python, regex

I have a bunch of codes with different numbers and with the occasional letter inserted to represent different modifiers of my data. Here is an example code: "01a-09B". What I want to do is:

1. Extract the number ranges from the code above
2. know if the letters "A" or "B" are attached to a number (i.e. [[1,"a"],[9,"b"]]

I am attempting to do this using python's Re package. My code follows:

```
>>>> print re.match(r'\D','01a-09B',re.M)
None
```

The problem is I can't match non-numeric characters with this code; I am getting `None` returned.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> m = re.search(r'(\d+)([A-Za-z]+)?\-(\d+)([A-Za-z]+)?', '01a-09B')
>>> m.groups()
('01', 'a', '09', 'B')
>>> m = re.search(r'(\d+)([A-Za-z]+)?\-(\d+)([A-Za-z]+)?', '01-09B')
>>> m.groups()
('01', None, '09', 'B')
```

Answer (score 2):

`.match` matches at the beginning of a string. You probably want `.search()` to match anywhere in the string.

Comment: `print re.search(r'^\D','01a-09B',re.M)` still returns `None`

Comment: `print re.search(r'(\D)','01a-09B',re.M).group(0)` -> `a`

Comment: @mh00h Because `re.search(r'^\D')` is equivalent to `re.match(r'\D')` since the `^` limits it to the beginning of the string. Your letters are not at the beginning of the string, so why are you trying to tie the match there?